# (Appium) Using sendKeys to write a number in an input field which already has a +91 hardcoded as a prefix, does not enter the number correctly

Tags: android, selenium, appium

It selects and copies the number which I am sending and sometimes enters it before the +91 which eventually results in an error.

Below is the code I am using to send a number in to the number input field.

```
WebElement number = driver.findElement(By.id("com.ulink.agrostar.debug:id/edt_enter_mobileNumber"));
number.sendKeys("7976358798");
```

[image]

Comment: To be clear, can you share the screenshot of the mobile number field? There is a bit confusion since +91 is hardcoded, it shouldn't be replaceable. Or if its editable, then just fetch the text first from the input field, append your sendkeys value to it and then send it back.

Comment: Hi Ashish, I have shared the screenshot. Also, yes the +91 is not editable.

Comment: Thanks. Try using "wait" for the text +91 to be visible. Then send keys.

Comment: It did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check whether your edit field consist of predefined field like 
"+91", If it is there you can override text like these.

```
    if(element.getText().trim().equals("+91")) {
       number.clear();
    } 
    number.sendKeys("+91" + "7976358798");
```

It should work please check.

Comment: Tried this. Not able to trim the +91. This code rather starts the number from 91 with +91 already being there.

Comment: above code will give you these +917976358798. What you want +917976358798 or 7976358798

Comment: can you send your apk to me. I can solve this for you at my end.  EmailId : jiteshmohite619@gmail.com

Comment: Sure! You can download the apk from this [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ulink.agrostar&hl=en)

Comment: Did you run the code on your end? The updated one also does not help.

Comment: Same thing. It is not clearing the +91 and if I send +91 along with the number it ends up with 91 two times then.

Comment: May I know what is your appium version?

Comment: It is appium 1.6.0